# How can I introduce (or name) a person who was my colleague?

Tags: vocabulary, names

How can I introduce (or name) a person who was my colleague, but he has changed jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You can say **my former colleague**.

Example:

> **My former colleague** now works for another company

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> This is my **former/previous colleague**... John
>
> This is John... **we used to work together**

Comment: Why someone downvote ?

Comment: @storgt2 - I have no idea. Both of these suggested options look good to me (I would probably punctuate them differently, but I don't think that's any reason for a downvote. Here, the ellipses indicate where a speaker would insert a brief pause.)